# rails nested hash with default values

Tags: ruby, hash

I'd like to create a new Hash with nested default values. I thought it should be like

```
h = Hash.new(count: 0, rating: 0)
```

So I can do stuff like

```
h['a'][:count] += 1
h['a'][:rating] += 1
```

and so on. But when I try it in the console it looks like this:

```
2.3.1 :046 > h = Hash.new(count: 0, rating: 0)
 => {} 
2.3.1 :047 > h["a"]
 => {:count=>0, :rating=>0} 
2.3.1 :048 > h["a"][:count]
 => 0 
2.3.1 :049 > h["a"][:count] += 1
 => 1 
2.3.1 :050 > h["b"][:count] += 1
 => 2
2.3.1 :051 > h
 => {}
```

**So my questions are:**

- Why is `h["b"][:count] += 1` returning 2 and not 1?
- why is h empty?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc for [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) explains the three ways of initializing a hash and, in your case, you are using an object in the Hash constructor:

> If obj is specified, this single object will be used for all default values.

If you want that each missing key creates it's own object, create the hash with a block, like this:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = { count: 0, rating: 0 } }
```

Then:

```
2.6.3 :012 > h
 => {} 
2.6.3 :013 > h['a'][:count] = 5
 => 5 
2.6.3 :015 > h
 => {"a"=>{:count=>5, :rating=>0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find this behaviour documented in the [`Hash::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Hash.html#method-c-new) documentation:

> ### new → new_hash
>
> ### new(obj) → new_hash
>
> ### new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash
>
> Returns a new, empty hash. If this hash is subsequently accessed by a
>   key that doesn't correspond to a hash entry, the value returned
>   depends on the style of new used to create the hash. In the first
>   form, the access returns `nil`. **If *obj* is specified, this single
>   object will be used for all *default values*.** If a block is
>   specified, it will be called with the hash object and the key, and
>   should return the default value. It is the block's responsibility to
>   store the value in the hash if required.
>
> ```rb
> h = Hash.new("Go Fish")
> h["a"] = 100
> h["b"] = 200
> h["a"]           #=> 100
> h["c"]           #=> "Go Fish"
> # The following alters the single default object
> h["c"].upcase!   #=> "GO FISH"
> h["d"]           #=> "GO FISH"
> h.keys           #=> ["a", "b"]
>
> # While this creates a new default object each time
> h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "Go Fish: #{key}" }
> h["c"]           #=> "Go Fish: c"
> h["c"].upcase!   #=> "GO FISH: C"
> h["d"]           #=> "Go Fish: d"
> h.keys           #=> ["c", "d"]
> ```

In your example `h["a"]` and `h["b"]` both return the exact same default hash object. Meaning that if you change `h["a"]`, `h["b"]` is also changed. Since you never set `h["a"]` or `h["b"]` the hash appears empty.

To assign a new hash on access you'll have to use the block syntax as [shown by luis.parravicini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58172710/3982562).